# What does the $\lor$ symbol mean in $A \lor I$ (where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph and $I$ is the identity matrix)?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

What does the $\lor$ symbol in, e.g., $(A \lor I)^n$ mean (given A is an adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ and $I$ the identity matrix)?

Searching online I could only find references to the logical or operator, which didn't seem to make sense.

Comment: If A is defined as a binary matrix, an element wise logic operator would make sense. Where did you encounter this?

Comment: Maybe a [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra)? It's the wrong way up if so. Or perhaps it's being used unconventionally to mean an elementwise product.

Comment: Graph theory, A is defined as an adjacency matrix. Would that mean I get as a result $A$ and all the ones in the diagonal (disregarding the power)? The meaning would be that each vertex in the graph also points to itself, doesn't that modify the graph? This was mentioned in the context of something called transient closure.

Comment: I interpret the expression exactly the way you just did, "each vertex in the graph also points to itself". Not sure what this is good for, but it sounds like it could be useful in the context of *transitive* closure (or reduction). Are you sure about the word "transient"? In any case, why not just fully disclose the source? This would allow us to rule out (or confirm) misinterpretations on your part.

Comment: It could be the symmetric product $A\vee B:=\frac12(A\otimes B+B\otimes A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on user3733558's comment, this is (probably) the binary "or" which is used to obtain the [transitive closure of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure).

Since $A$ and $I$ are $0-1$ matrices, one can interpret "0" as false 'there is no edge between $i$ and $j$' and "1" as true  'there is an edge between $i$ and $j$'.

We work in the boolean semi-ring (in a nutshell the multiplication is the "and" operator ($\wedge$) and the addition the "or" operator ($\vee$)). You can extend the matrix multiplication to this ring $A \otimes B = \bigvee_k A_{i,k} \wedge B_{k,j}$.

In the usual real semi-ring, the coefficient $(A^n)_{i,j}$ is the number of path between $i$ and $j$ of length exactly $n$ in the graph (this is a nice induction), and $(A+I)^n_{i,j}$ is the number of path between $i$ and $j$ of length at most $n$.

In the boolean semi-ring the coefficient $(A^n)_{i,j}$ (matrix multiplication is define as above) is $1$ if there exists a path between $i$ and $j$ of length exactly $n$ in the graph, $0$ otherwise (once again, an induction shows this), thus $(A\vee I)^n_{i,j}$ is $1$ if there exists a path between $i$ and $j$ of length at most $n$ in the graph, $0$ otherwise.

Notice that if your graph has $|V|$ vertices, then if there exists a path of length at most $n$ between $i$ and $j$, then there exists a path of length at most $|V|$, so the sequence  $(A\vee I)^n$ is stationary (call  $(A\vee I)^*$ its limit), and this limit is the transitive closure $\bar{G}$ of $G$ defined equivalently as
$$\bar{G}_{i,j}=1 \Longleftrightarrow \text{ there exists a path between $i$ and $j$ in } G$$

---

More generally, working in different semi-ring allows to defines some structural properties and algorithms as matrix multiplication. For instance one can computes the shortest-paths using $\max$ as addition and $+$ as multiplication [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Applications_and_generalizations)