# Constructing graph $G'$ that has double path between 2 vertices in $G$

Tags: graph-theory

**Question**: The square of a directed graph  $G=\left< V, E\right>$ is the graph  $G=\left< V, E^2\right>$ such that $(u,w) \ in E^2 $ iff  for some $v \in V$, both $(u,v) \in E$  and  $(v,w) \in E$. That is $G$ contains a path with **EXACTLY two edges** between $u$ and $w$. Describe efficient algorithms for computing $G^2$ from $G$ for both the adjacency list and adjacency-matrix representations of $G$. Analyze the running times of your algorithms.

**Attempt**:

What we did here is that w loop through all vertices $v$ of $G$ and then add another nested loop to loop through all $u$ adjacent to $v$ and finally another loop of all vertices $w$ in $G$ that are adjacent to $u$ and add them to $E^2$.

[image]

**Problem**:

Running time as I see it is $O(V+V\times E \times E)= (V+VE^2)$, but what I got is as follows:

1. We construct the edges in time $O(VE)$? Is it because we have $V$ vertices and $E=\Sigma_v(deg(v)) = 2m = E$ please?
2. After edges satisfying $E^2$ property is constructed, in $O(VE)$, we remove duplicates in time $O(V+ E\times E) = O(V+ E\times V)$, so total time is  which $O(VE) + O(V+ E\times V)$. So, why please $O(V+ E\times E) = O(V+ E\times V)$?

Comment: A nice way to obtain this is to square the adjacency matrix $A$ in the boolean ring. The complexity will be $O(V^3)$ if you do it in a naive way (faster using fast matrix multiplication). See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134952/what-does-the-lor-symbol-mean-in-a-lor-i-where-a-is-the-adjacency-matri/4135072#4135072

Comment: @thibo, thank you. I am not looking for extra input please. Appreciate your effor. I am just looking analyze above please. Why we got it in that way.